# Xubuntu: How to prevent Thunar from auto-opening a specific usb thumb drive?

Tags: usb, xubuntu

I have one specific usb thumb drive that I use to store a git repository. When I plug it in, I'd like it to mount automatically, but without opening a Thunar window showing the content of the thumb drive. I only use *git push* and *git pull* commands to access the contents of the drive, so a popping up Thunar window just blocks my workflow.

Just to emphasize: I do want Thunar to open up every time I stick in **any other** usb drive.

Thank you for your support! :)

(P.S. I know this forum is for Ubuntu, but in case you happen to know a similar solution for Windows 10, I'd like to know that too, because I use the same usb drive in a Windows machine too.)

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and run

```
thunar-volman-settings
```

Uncheck the 3. option (my system not english so i dont know what write in english)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the answer I'm looking for. This would disable Thunar from opening for all USB drives.